# Limiting access to Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azureportal

I am trying to limit the access to my Azure Portal form only a certain device like my personal device or my colleague devices. I don't want to use the IP limitation because my ISP change my public IP very often. I don't want to use a Microsoft Intune because it's my personal device and not a corporate device. Does anyone know a solution to this situation?

I did try the IP limitation solution, but my public IP allows change.
I try to limit the access to a certain platform, but it's not the result that I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You have the following Control access Enforcement to block or grant access:
[image]

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/concept-conditional-access-grant

So, the most effective way to limit access by a device is used "Requiere Hybrid Azure AD Joined device".

I understand that you don´t want these options, but it is the only viable way.

Hope this helps!